# pip3 install opencv is looking at the wrong URL

Tags: debian, python, pip, opencv, devuan

I'm trying to install opencv with `pip3` on my Devuan GNU/Linux 3, and this is what happens:

```
$ pip3 install opencv
Collecting opencv
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/opencv
```

and indeed, if you browse that URL, you get a 404 page.

Why is this happening? Am I to blame? Devuan? pypi.org administrators? Somebody else?

Also - can I replace the URL somehow? Or manually install from somewhere?

Comment: Please see the choices https://pypi.org/search/?q=opencv

Comment: `pip3 install opencv-python`. The package is not called `opencv` sicne it's a Python binding.

Comment: @hoefling: Make this an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The package is named `opencv-python` on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/), so install it instead of non-existent `opencv`:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the [OpenCV source file](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#files) and install it using `pip`. The installation file will have a **.whl** or Wheel filetype. You can [download this one if you're on x86_64](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/aa/5880b514dff3642161bda4af39aa2a544cb5949d9e194d1ef81e06fcc2f2/opencv_python-4.2.0.34-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl)

Now go to the download location and type -

`pip3 install opencv`

Press **Tab** for auto-completion of the filename. It should be easily installed this way.

Comment: You mean, it'll be a file which begins with opencv? Also, is the second link the result of a build of the source in the first link?

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right